# How to control display brightness on Intel hardware?

Tags: power-management, intel-graphics

I'm working with a Sony Vaio BZ-12 Notebook and want to know how to manage the brightness of my display, especially when it's in eco-mode.

The designated Graphic-Accelerator is the Intel GM45.
With the 10.04 release I could control the brightness with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys, but not all the time.

Comment: This isn't likely to be related to the Intel display adapter, but rather to detection of the Fn keys or Vaio-specific hardware drivers. Test whether the brightness slider in System ▸ Preferences ▸ Power Management works, and use one of the methods described [on this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LaptopTestingTeam/Old/HotkeyResearch) to find out whether a keycode is being generated when you press the Fn keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ændrük said, this is probably not actually related to the intel driver, but if you want to adjust the backlight manually, you can set it via the command line using sysfs.

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/[whatever driver, usually there is only 1 just just tab complete this]/max_brightness
```

To see what the max is, then

```
echo [whatever brightness] | sudo tee - /sys/class/backlight/[same driver]/brightness
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is `intel_backlight`.

My laptop has Intel HD 3000 integrated graphics in my i3 2350m CPU in a Toshiba Satellite.

For very dim use `$ sudo intel_backlight 1` and `$ sudo intel_backlight 100` for full brightness.

Also, the lowest I can go with the normal ACPI, is 9% brightness according to `intel_backlight`, so going to 1% brightness is much brighter than the normal "lowest" backlight.

Answer (score 0):

Install `xgamma` and its a breeze, you can set gamma with command `xgamma -gamma xx` where `xx` is your value.